# How do I add a condition to my Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, match, vlookup

I would like Excel to execute the following formula ONLY if B2 has a value in it. How do I write that into this formula?

`=IF( ISNUMBER( MATCH( MATCH(A2,AllResources4[Title],0), SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(AllResources4[[#Headers],[Title]], ROW(AllResources4[Title]) - ROW(AllResources4[[#Headers],[Title]]),))*(ROW(AllResources4[Title]) - ROW(AllResources4[[#Headers],[Title]])),0)), VLOOKUP(A2,AllResources4[#All],8,0),"")`

I want Excel to look for A2 in the "AllResources4" table or return the result only if its corresponding B2 cell has a value. Same with A3, A4, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),Formula,"")
```

The ISBLANK function will check if a cell is blank (has no value), combined with a if statement will run your formula only when B2 has something in it.  The above formula will output nothing if B2 is blank.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the logic. It appears as though it reads: "if B2 is blank, then execute the formula, otherwise return blank." The above formula creates blanks along the whole column even though many cells in the B column have values. I switched it around and that way doesn't work either. It just executes the formula for all cells.

Comment: This is the updated formula I used: =IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(MATCH(A2,AllResources4[Title],0),SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(AllResources4[[#Headers],[Title]],ROW(AllResources4[Title])-ROW(AllResources4[[#Headers],[Title]]),))*(ROW(AllResources4[Title])-ROW(AllResources4[[#Headers],[Title]])),0)),VLOOKUP(A2,AllResources4[#All],8,0)))

Comment: I figured it out. Even though the cells were visibly blank, they were returning values of zero. Therefore, I changed the formula to: =IF(B2=0,"",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(MATCH(A2,AllResources4[Title],0),SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(AllResources4[[#Headers],[Title]],ROW(AllResources4[Title])-ROW(AllResources4[[#Headers],[Title]]),))*(ROW(AllResources4[Title])-ROW(AllResources4[[#Headers],[Title]])),0)),VLOOKUP(A2,AllResources4[#All],8,0)))

Answer (score 2):

Using ISBLANK is the way to go. However, I sometimes get sketched out since you can't see how ISBLANK is actually working. That being said, it sometimes it worth inserting a column next to your data dedicated to the ISBLANK function. Something like:

=IF(ISBLANK(cell),0,1)

Then, you can check to make sure that the function works and use sort/filter to get the cells that you need to use the function on. Of course, if you want the function applied to all the data but only to work on the non-blank cells, you could add a clause to the IF for whether the column value we jsut made is one or zero.

***NOTE**** if you are working with numbers, the count function might also be helpful

Comment: Thank you! Creating a column next to the data helped me troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2):

This worked! =IF(B2=0,"",Formula)